# How to query an object using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get a table name dynamically, by the use of a variable, but when I bring this table back, I cant query it using LINQ.

First Step: I Get the table Name by the use of a parameter

`var tableName = GetTable("Customer");`

Second Step:

```
  public static object GetTable(string tblName)
    {
        ALLDBEntities db = new ALLDBEntities();

        var table = db.GetType().GetProperty(tblName).GetValue(db) as IEnumerable;

        return table;
    }
```

this is what I want to achieve

```
public List<Records> GetNonDuplicateRecords(string tableName)
      {

          ThreeEntities threeentities = new ThreeEntities();

          List<Records> recs = (from p in threeentities.TableName "Should use this"

                                select new Records
                                {
                                    _claimNumber = p.ClaimNumber,
                                    _firstname = p.PatientFirstName,
                                    _lastname = p.PatientLastName,
                                    _client = p.Client
                                }).ToList<Records>();

          return recs;
      }
```

This return me my table/dbset as expected and I cast as IEnumerable, but when I try to query this dataset/table using LINQ, it doesn't allow me to

any help with this ?

Comment: "it doesn't allow me to" What does that mean? What error do you get, if any?

Comment: Why you don't provide a method in `ALLDBEntities` that takes a `string tblName` and returns the items according to this name(for example using `switch`).

Comment: this is my context file

Comment: By the way: casting to `IEnumerable` is completely pointless in your case as you return just an `object`. So in your client-code you´d have to cast again. Apart from this to *perform* a cast you have to know the type at *compile*-time.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I cant access the collection

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable does not extend the LINQ stuff. You must use the generic IEnumerable. As you do not have the type of the table you must create the generic IEnumerable type through reflection

//Edit [21.09.2018]

Please have a look at following code.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var records = GetNonDuplicateRecords("Records");
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> GetTable<T>(string tblName)
    {
        ALLDBEntities db = new ALLDBEntities();

        var table = db.GetType().GetProperty(tblName).GetValue(db) as List<T>;

        return table.AsQueryable();
    }


    public static List<Records> GetNonDuplicateRecords(string tableName)
    {
        List<Records> recs = (from p in GetTable<RecordTable>(tableName)

                            select new Records
                            {
                                _claimNumber = p.ClaimNumber,
                                _firstname = p.PatientFirstName,
                                _lastname = p.PatientLastName,
                                _client = p.Client
                            }).ToList<Records>();

        return recs;
    }

    public class Records
    {
        public object _claimNumber { get; set; }
        public object _firstname { get; internal set; }
        public object _lastname { get; internal set; }
        public object _client { get; internal set; }
    }

    public class RecordTable
    {
        public object ClaimNumber { get; set; }
        public object PatientFirstName { get; internal set; }
        public object PatientLastName { get; internal set; }
        public object Client { get; internal set; }
    }

    public class ALLDBEntities
    {
        public List<RecordTable> Records { get; set; } = new List<RecordTable>
        {
            new RecordTable{ClaimNumber = "asdadsasd"}
        };
    }
```

Instead of `GetValue(db) as List` you must use `GetValue(db) as DbSet` if you are working with EF. It is not completely clear to me right now if you using EF or something else.

Some hints:
Though you've edited your code it is not clear to me on which data you are operating on. It seems to me that `Record`is not your DB Model. If this holds true, you are not able to select a "normal" C# class from a DB Model when using EF + linq2sql unless you are calling ToList() or something first.
The reason is that your select must be transformed into plain SQL and the underlying SQL provider jsut does not know how it can express your `select => new Record()` in raw SQL.

Comment: This is pretty vague for a specific answer. Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: You're right. Indeed it is not possible to cast the object to a generic iEnumerable and access it during compiletime in a typesafe way without knowing the type at compiletime. Sry for the confusion.

Comment: have you any examples of this?

Comment: @chris12345 please have a look at the edited answer and let me know if I'm wrong in my assumptions or if you need some further help.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
IEnumerable<object> tableName = (IEnumerable<object>)GetTable("Customer");
```

You have to cast the object received from GetTable.
Casting before returning does not help in this case.

Comment: done what you said still cant access it - var test = (from x in tableName.Where(x=> x.))

Comment: what type of Items are there in your IEnumerable (int/string/custom class)?

Comment: they are rows of data from a table, so a mixture of data types

Comment: Try this :

var test = from x in tableName
                        where x.ToString().Equals("")
                        select x;

Comment: Change the where condition to any specific boolean condition.

Comment: how will this help me query the data?

Comment: threeentities.TableName "Should use this"

What does this statement do?

Comment: @chris12345 of course you can not access the property "ClaimNumber". This property does not exist at the type "object". As already said, if you want to access the properties, you must know the Type of that object at compiletime. If you do not, you must build your query using Expressions or reflection. Both will work. But I think using Expressions directly will be faster.

Comment: @chris12345 Maybe I find some time today evening then I can give you an example how to use expressions for this. maybe someone else will do this until then.